# Quantum Mechanics in Electric Field

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem

I asked this problem in Physics SE but I did not get any useful answers except one. I believe asking this question here would be more beneficial owing to the Mathematical nature of the problem.

I am working on a problem which looks like this.

> Consider a charged particle with charge $q$ trapped in a box of length $L$ with finite constant potential $ V_0 $ on both ends. A constant (static) electric field of magnitude $F$ is applied from $- \infty $ to $+ \infty$.

My approach to the problem: I have divided the whole domain in three regions

- from $-\infty $ to $0$ as region $I$
- from $0 $ to $L$ as region $II$
- from $L$ to $+\infty$ as region $III$

Equations:

- The Schrodinger equation for region $II$ is : $-(\hbar^2/2m) \ d^2\psi/dx^2 + qFx =E\psi $
- The Schrodinger equation for region $I$ & $III$is : $-(\hbar^2/2m) \ d^2\psi/dx^2 + qFx +V_0=E\psi $

$\hbar = h/2\pi$

Solutions :

- Region $I$ : $\psi(x) = c_4 A_i[\alpha(V_0 + Fqx - E_n)] + c_5 B_i[\alpha(V_0 + Fqx - E_n)]$
- Region $II$ : $\psi(x) = c_1 A_i[\alpha( Fqx - E_n)] + c_2 B_i[\alpha(Fqx - E_n)]$
- Region $III$ : $\psi(x) = c_3 A_i[\alpha( V_0 + Fqx - E_n)]$ (The $Bi$ part is excluded because it blows up on $+\infty$.)

where $c_1 , c_2 , c_3 , c_4 , c_5$ are constants, $\alpha = (2^{1/3}m/\hbar^2 (Fmq/\hbar^2)^{2/3})$, $A_i$ and $B_i$ are Airy functions of first and second kind respectively, and $E_n$ are energy eigenvalues.

Applying the boundary conditions gives the following four equations:

- $ c_4 A_i[\alpha(V_0  - E_n)] + c_5 B_i[\alpha(V_0  - E_n)] =  c_1 A_i[\alpha( - E_n)] + c_2 B_i[\alpha(- E_n)]$
- $ c_4 A_i'[\alpha(V_0  - E_n)] + c_5 B_i'[\alpha(V_0 - E_n)] = c_1 A_i'[\alpha( - E_n)] + c_2 B_i'[\alpha(- E_n)]$
- $c_1 A_i[\alpha( FqL - E_n)] + c_2 B_i[\alpha(FqL - E_n)] = c_3 A_i[\alpha( V_0 + FqL - E_n)]$
- $c_1 A_i'[\alpha( FqL - E_n)] + c_2 B_i'[\alpha(FqL - E_n)] = c_3 A_i'[\alpha( V_0 + FqL - E_n)]$

> My query is how do I calculate the bound states $E_n$ from these equations. Also, I am bogged down by the fact that on both ends of the box $\psi$ behaves differently from what is seen in trivial problems. 
>   Also, I can use computational software like MATLAB, so if someone can help me with the computational technique to find $E_n$, that is perfectly fine.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143059/2451

Comment: The determinant of the set of 4 equations should be zero. Nonzero determent means that there is  a unique solution for the C-i and you know that c_i =0 is a solution. Nontrivial solutions can thus only exist if the determinant is equal to zero, which gives you the energy eigenvalues. The fact that the c_i are not fixed means that you need to normalize the wavefunction.